# How to show a rotating object in popover type window in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, uipopover

I need to show in my unity project that when i click on a GUI.button a popover like window opens and a 3D custom object is shown rotating automatically on some time interval. And I also need to know that is it possible to show another scene(rotating object) in a window inside main scene or we need something else for creating a view like popover? And if it is possible then any help is invited..Thanx..!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put another camera on the scene and put it on a portion of screen setting the rect variables.

You can also on/off it by code.

Build the popover scene far from original scene so the main camera do not include it or (advanced) configure the cullingmask to filter the rendered objects.